# Compute the solutions of the following equation in Fourier space:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, partial-derivative, transformation

$$\frac{d^3u}{dx^3}
− αxu = 0, x ∈ R, $$
where $ α > 0$ is some constant and $u(x)$ is assumed to satisfy $\int_R
u(x) dx = π.$

I know this is a ODE so this is what I came up with so far: 
$$i\omega^3\hat{U} -(-i)\frac{\partial}{\partial{\omega}}\alpha\hat{U} = 0$$ by canceling the the $i$ we are left with $$\omega^3\hat{U} +\frac{\partial}{\partial{\omega}}\alpha\hat{U} = 0$$ so

$\hat{U}(\omega) =C(\omega)e^{\frac{\omega^3}{\alpha}}$ After we take the Fourier transform of the equation and we get

$$u(x)= \int^\infty_{-\infty} c(x)e^{\frac{\omega^3}{\alpha}}e^{-i\omega x}$$ then I got very stumped, please any input is most welcome. I know how to solve for Pde but got confused for an ODE.

Comment: Firstly your solution to the differential equation for $\hat{U}$ is incorrect. Secondly, this ODE has basically no nice solutions: they're all in terms of hypergeometric functions.

Comment: Can you explain why or..?